# Rails console—Can't access object's attributes (though I can access the object itself)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, has-many-through

I have a `has_many through` relationship between `user` and `organisation`, with an `org_access` table joining them.

In Rails Console I type:

```
user = User.first
org_access = user.org_access
```

And it prints out:

```
=> [#<OrgAccess:0x007fe06632aa20 id: 1, organisation_id: 1, user_id: 1, access_status: 0, role: 0>]
```

But if I try:

```
org_access.role
user.role
user.organisation.role
```

None of these commands will return the `role` field in the `org_access`. How do I access a user+organisation's `org_access` fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`org_access` is an **array**. A `has_many` association always represents 0 or more items.

You need `org_access[0].role` etc.